# GoDaddy Issues Displaying JSON data in Maps Window

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, google-maps

I'm in need of a second set of eyes, here.  I have ran the following code in a console and it returns what's in the image, below.

I embed the code in html on [my web page](http://www.stormtrackerwx.com/index_beta.html) and nothing.  I've tried getting JSON by url, using https:// and still nothing.  Is this a GoDaddy web server issue or am I just doomed to display this data, all together?

```
   var obj = "";

    function initMap() {
        var hc = {lat: 40.4512, lng: -85.3700};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 4,
            center: hc
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: obj
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: hc,
            map: map,
            title: 'Hartford City'
        });
        marker.addListener('click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }

    var downloadJSON = function() {
        $.getJSON( "ajax/GeoObs.json", function( data ) {
            var items = [];
            items.push( "<li id='Weather'>Weather: " + data.features[0].properties.Weather + "</li>");
            items.push( "<li id='Weather'>Temp: " + data.features[0].properties.Temp + "</li>");
            items.push( "<li id='Weather'>Wind: " + data.features[0].properties.Wind + "</li>");
            obj = $('<div>').append($( "<ul/>", { class: "my-new-list", html: items.join("") })).html();
            initMap();
        });
    }
                </script><script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCz672JUYjod6zzfxnBg_rzBNsBfbbjpJc&callback=initMap">
```

[image]

Comment: `downloadJSON` is a function.  Where are you calling it?

Comment: Don't give `obj` such a broad scope.  Create it in `downloadJSON` and then pass it into `initMap()` as an argument.  The map isn't going to update automatically if you adjust `obj` later.

Comment: Building on @geocodezip's comment, I put a breakpoint in your `downloadJSON` function and it never gets called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `downloadJSON` function is never getting called.

Edit your Google Maps API `<script>` to call `downloadJSON` instead of `initMap` when it loads:

Example:

```
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCz672JUYjod6zzfxnBg_rzBNsBfbbjpJc&callback=downloadJSON"></script>
```

Comment: Hi zero298!  Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried this and it kills the map, completely and instead loads a blank page.  Is there somewhere else I should be making this call?

Comment: What does your console say?  Is it giving you an error?

Comment: @user5834454 I'm positive this is the issue.  I just created a static server that proxies yours and edited the google maps script to call `downloadJSON` and my map is loading correctly without having to run anything in console.

Comment: you're right!  Chrome is blocking the script from running, because it says it's running from an "unauthenticated source".  Gotta find a way around that, but it does load in IE.  Thank you!